# Upstart - execute script at boot when network is not available

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, shell-script, upstart

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a command/script at boot only if the network is not available (eth0, wlan0) toconnect to a Bluetooth access point (NAP). I understand that `upstart` is one way to do it but how do I define 'network not present'?